# Binding error not due to my code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF custom UserControl defined like that:

```
<UserControl x:Name="parent" [..]>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="StatusValues" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type core:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="s:Status" />
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            [..]
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=parent, Path=DataContext.StatusFilter}">
                                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                    <CompositeCollection>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Black">All</ComboBoxItem>
                                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusValues}}" />
                                    </CompositeCollection>
                                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I removed a lot of stuff for readability but I let what I think is essential for describing the problem. Do not hesitate to ask me for more code if needed.

The goal of this user control is to add filtering capabilities to the DataGrid. Among others columns, there is a Status column. When the user picks up a status in the header's combo-box, only the elements with that status are displayed in the grid.

Everything actually works well. The selected status is well bound to my view model. The rows are well filtered, etc. My only concern is about the following errors I am getting:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

I do not even use `RelativeSource` and all this stuff myself. My guess is that it is used under the hood by the framework or something.

**But how can I avoid these errors?** The application is running on .NET 4.5.2.

I have read solutions about setting the style of the ComboBoxItem, but it does not solve my problem. I have read threads explaining this happens when the collection source is filtered, but that's not the case of my ComboBox collection view.

Comment: Filtering is best done via a ICollectionView, such as CollectionViewSource

Comment: That's what I am doing in the ViewModel. But the issue is not the filtering. It is the binding error I am getting on a binding I am not setting myself.

Comment: The erroneous binding is set by `ComboBoxItem` default style, because `ComboBoxItem` is designed to be used specifically in `ComboBox.Items` collection. Consider replacing it with some other type (preferably the type of `StatusFilter` property on your view-model).

Comment: @MikeT No, the error is thrown by the combobox mapping (when I comment out the CombBox, there no more errors, and look at the end of the error: `target element is 'ComboBoxItem'`). The line you are talking about is used to retrieve the DataGridColumn Header value.

Comment: @Grx70 as I said, I tried to set the style of the ComboBoxItem but it does not solve it. How would you do that? I may did somethong wrong!

Comment: You may be mislead by what `setting the style` means when you bind a ComboBox.Item source every item is wrapped in a ComboBoxItem before being added to the items collection. you have no direct access to this comboBoxItem however if you provide a Style for this then that will be applied during creation, because of this shouldn't add a comboBoiitem to the collection that is bound to the item source, you could try adding the raw string then setting the foreground on a dataTrigger

Comment: Ok, my mistake. It seems like `ComboBox` is setting these bindings directly. It only adds to the point that what you're doing here is a misuse of `ComboBoxItem`, and getting rid of these warnings might be possible, but I think is not worth the while - you'd probably have to subclass `ComboBox` and override couple of methods without calling the base implementation, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @MikeT I am sorry but how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are Hosting a ComboboxItem inside of a ComboboxItem, a ComboboxItem is designed to be hosted in a Combobox and binds itself to the ComboBox's VerticalContentAlignment & HorizontalContentAlignment

this is because when you set the item source the binding creates a ComboboxItem with a ContentTemplate set to the Combobox's ItemTemplate and a DataContent set to the item in the item source

so you need to remove your ComboBoxItem from the composite collection and style the item container

eg

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Filter}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/> <!--Default Value-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="All"> <!--Using the default binding ie DataContext and if it has a Value of All do the following-->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <clr:String xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">All</clr:String> 
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Statuses}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need for the `ItemContainerStyle` since replacing  `<ComboBoxItem Foreground="Black">All</ComboBoxItem>` by `<clr:String xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">All</clr:String>`, the ComboBoxItem is already in black.

Comment: not necessary foreground could be overridden at an eariler point in the visual tree